# Wait/Pause an amount of seconds in C

Tags: c, windows

I wrote a little console application, and I want it to pause for a certain number of seconds before the cycle (a while) starts again.

I'm working on Windows operating system.

Comment: I don't think that `seconds` is a very useful tag.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

On Windows, the function to do this is `Sleep`, which takes the amount of *milliseconds* you want to sleep. To use `Sleep`, you need to include `windows.h`.

On POSIX-Systems, the function `sleep` (from `unistd.h`) accomplishes this:

```
   unsigned int sleep(unsigned int seconds);

   DESCRIPTION
          sleep()  makes  the  calling thread sleep until
          seconds seconds have elapsed or a signal arrives which is not ignored.
```

If it is interrupted by a signal, the remaining time to sleep is returned. If you use signals, a more robust solution would be:

```
 unsigned int time_to_sleep = 10; // sleep 10 seconds
 while(time_to_sleep)
     time_to_sleep = sleep(time_to_sleep);
```

This is of course assuming your signal-handlers only take a negligible amount of time. (Otherwise, this will delay the main program longer than intended)

Comment: it seems that with Windows "sleep()" is a no-no.

Answer (score 3):

easy:

```
while( true )
{
    // your stuff
    sleep( 10 ); // sleeping for 10 seconds
};
```

Comment: Passing the argument 10 will not give you 10 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

On [**UNIX**](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sleep):

```
#include <unistd.h>
sleep(10); // 10 seconds
```

On [**Windows**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
#include <windows.h>
Sleep(10000); // 10 seconds (10000 milliseconds)
```

Note the difference between `sleep()` (UNIX) and `Sleep()` (Windows).

Comment: In your example, Unix will wait for `10000` seconds and not `10` seconds.

Comment: @HamzaAnis : not in my code::blocks compiling. Number 10 makes my program wait for 10 seconds. Tested on Linux and BSD.