# Is there no way to Wait in C#?

Tags: c#, wait

There is a command that usually makes the program wait. Now I know how to make the Program wait while also freezing all input, but that's not what I'm trying to achieve. I'm making a simple Windows Console Application, just to start me up on things.

```
     String name;
        Console.WriteLine("What is your name?");
        name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, {0}", name);
```

Now I'd like to have it wait while also allowing any input, so that way I could run something else, but also have it to where you can actually have it say `Hello, (Insert Name Here)`

And also, as mentioned before that I'm very new, please try to explain what you're answer involves, thanks!

Comment: `Console.ReadLine()` does the waiting for you. I'm not sure then what you're looking for, unfortunately.

Comment: Yep check this link someone asked the exact same question before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9241025/wait-pause-an-amount-of-seconds-in-c

Comment: If You ask about "wait" conception in wide perspective and diferent languages, waiting in context of console user input dont fit to typical meaning. Usually "wait" concept in near to threads, synchonicuty etc.

Answer (score 0):

Outside of ReadLine which you are already using that waits for user input, Thread.Sleep as in below is one basic method of stopping the application for X amount of time to wait for an execution to finish or a user to be ready. Thread.Sleep blocks execution though in more complex applications:

```
Thread.Sleep(2000);
```

Getting into an advanced way, you can use Asynchronous programming concepts and use Task.Delay. This doesn't block a thread like sleep and it means you can do this using a single thread using the async programming model. This sample code creates a new method, says it's async and defines it as a Task which is basically a unit of work, again more advanced concept wise but just to give you a high level idea/overview.

```
async Task TaskDelay()
{
    await Task.Delay(2000);
} 

private async void Test()  
{
    // Console.WriteLine etc. etc

    await PutTaskDelay();
    MessageBox.Show("Hello, I'm done waiting.");
}
```

Comment: I'm not getting into a best practices discussion, this was meant as a simple example that he would understand with very limited background. As it stands it will work and it works for an extended example without getting too deep into the subject. I think you are overextending yourself on semantics.

Comment: It's easy enough to just say `async Task`, so why not just do it?

Answer (score -1):

I believe the question is:

*How do wait in the main thread for user input, while working on some other task in the background?*

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AsynchronousTask();
        Console.WriteLine("What is your name?");
        var name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, {0}", name);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static async void AsynchronousTask()
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                Console.WriteLine("Async tas is running in the background.");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                Thread.Sleep(1000); //this is just to slowdown background thread
            }
        });
    }
}
```

While this example is very basic it shows how to get some code running in background. The topic you may wish to explore is called [Asynchronous Programing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx)

Comment: @Nkosi yes it can, but what does that have to do with code I've posted ?